# Need to implement a timeout feature when application goes to background

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I need to create a timeout feature when my app goes to the background for 5 minutes(anything that fires up onPause() except when activity is finishing). If the user goes back to the application then the timer should be cancelled.

Also, I need the timer to be not dependent on the time set in the phone meaning when the app goes to the background and then the user changes the time the application will still timeout within 5 minutes.

Checking out the documentation of the AlarmManager it states the following:

```
Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code       
run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal 
timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use 
Handler.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try setting up [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - these can operate in background even if user toggles frontmost application. you can communicate with the service using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), just as you would do with threads.

the easiest would be to use sendEmptyMessageDelayed of predefined type and use call to removeMessages() once your app is back on top.

Comment: I think this tutorial will be handy to get your hands dirty with services: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for_04.html - i've been using it myself. actually start-stop service will only have one side-effect for you - your application could be destroyed, but the service would survive this (once started - it must be stopped, while bound services die the second the last client is gone). now, binding service is well explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. look up LocalService code snippet, it's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the easiest solution wouldn't be to just set a value in sharedPreferences when your activity pauses and test this value again onResume. To avoid the value being corrupted by the user changing the clock you could employ SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() or SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can easily program your app to run at a specific time or every 5 minutes with a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). You can cancel it with the same PendingIntent.

I don't know about the time dependency but it's easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

in `onPause()` set an alarm using `AlarmManager`, like this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Alarm time is elapsed time since boot (including sleep) plus 5 minutes
long alarmTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5 * 60 * 1000;
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

For the `pendingIntent()` you can use either a broadcast Intent or you can have it start one of your activities. Depends what you want to do when the alarm goes off.

**NOTE: Using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` ensures that changes the user makes to his date/time settings won't have any effect on your 5 minute timeout.**

Make sure to cancel the alarm when your app resumes (in `onResume()`) and when it finishes (in `onDestroy()`)